# Steps to overlay a solid color over some regions of an image

Tags: gimp, inkscape

I have an image:

[image]

Over this i want to overlay solid colors in some regions. Those regions are colored black here.

[image]

I want the black color to be blue.

Now I have the raw image. How do I massage it to create the second image with black replaced by blue? One option was Gimp select by color. But then select by color also selects all black regions in the image even inside the map.

Worst case I will proceed with that.

Is there a way to do it in Inkscape? I Googled and think it can be done through layers option in Inkscape, but how exactly?

Comment: I think you need to make what you are asking a little clearer. On the face of it, it looks like you could just draw blue shapes instead of black shapes. Also, please ad your images into the post rather than providing links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the fuzzy-select (magic wand) it will only select the contiguous areas and so won't select things inside the colored parts bits.

However if you still have both images, you can load them both as layers in on Gimp image, make the blackened one visible, use it as a guide to create a polygon selection (lasso tool, just shift click on corners) and activate the other mayer and bucket-fill the resulting selection

Comment: thanks! magic wand selection works. but i am such a noob at gimp, i cannot figure how to fill it with desired color.

Comment: Bucket-fill, tick "fill whole selection", and click somewhere on the selection. You can also just drag the color from the color indicators under the Tools palette, to your image.

Comment: thanks! that works! but i have some more maps for which i don't even have the second figure. Could you outline steps to do this given only the first image?